# Creating random differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, random

I'm working on an educational project and new to Mathematica Language. Can I create,like multivariance equations with different f[x] in y'[x]=f[x] by using one function? The output should be like this:

[image: differential equations]

I have problems with realization so any help is good.
Thanks in advance.

Added some code:

```
a1 = RandomInteger[Range[-1, 1]];
a2 = RandomInteger[Range[-1, 1]];
a3 = RandomInteger[Range[-1, 1]];
d = RandomChoice[Range[1, 3]];
randtri = RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos, Exp}];

eqn := {y'[t] == RandomChoice[Range[5]] y[t] + a1*randtri[t] + a2*y[t]*randtri[t] + a3*Power[y[t], d]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this answer part of what you are looking for?

We can use `RandomChoice` to select different components of a differential equation.  (Other `Random` functions could also be suitable)

```
eqn := {y'[t] == RandomChoice[Range[7]] y[t] + RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos, Exp}][t], 
        y[0] == RandomChoice[Range[4]]}
```

Every time `eqn` is evaluated, we get a different equation

```
eqn
(* {Derivative[1][y][t] == Cos[t] + 6 y[t], y[0] == 2} *)
```

which we can solve

```
DSolve[%, y[t], t]
(* {{y[t] -> 1/37 (80 E^(6 t) - 6 Cos[t] + Sin[t])}} *)
```

Extending this to multiple variables is not too hard.

Comment: Thanks,thats's it! I suppose, after that can use TraditionalForm function to get the output like on image I posted earlier?

Comment: `TraditionalForm` will give a (different) conventional mathematical representation of the equation, in terms of `y'(t)`, rather than `dy/dt`, but presumably suitable for generating problem sheets.

Comment: got it, but now I have only blank graphs like here: https://ibb.co/64YjMwv

Comment: Your solution has an undefined constant `C1`. Your equation needs to specify boundary conditions

Comment: So DSolve function has to get additional parameters, added y[0] == -1 in {} branches and got the graph.